# SQL Error returned in php for query with joins

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to populate a table by executing the below query for a php application:

```
$sql3 = "SELECT distinct(`t1.testName`), `t2.comments AS C1` from `sample AS t1` left join `sample AS t2` ON `t1.testName`= `t2.testName` where `t1.buildNumber`= 181 and `t2.buildNumber`= 180 and `t1.errorStackTrace` is not null";

$result3 = mysqli_query($dbconnect,$sql3);

if(!mysqli_query($dbconnect, $sql3)){
    printf("error message: %s\n",mysqli_error($dbconnect));
}
```

I am seeing the following error returned:

```
error message: Table 'testdata.sample as t1' doesn't exist
```

I have tried a lot to fix this but couldn't. The query runs fine when run on mysql. 
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: use proper back quotes or remove  `$sql3 = "SELECT distinct(t1.testName), t2.comments AS C1 from sample AS t1 left join sample AS t2 ON t1.testName= t2.testName where t1.buildNumber= 181 and t2.buildNumber= 180 and t1.errorStackTrace is not null";
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the backticks only arround table names or column names not including the alias:

```
$sql3 = "SELECT distinct(`t1`.`testName`), `t2`.`comments` AS C1 from `sample` AS ` left join `sample` AS t2 ON t1.testName= t2.testName where t1.buildNumber= 181 and t2.buildNumber= 180 and t1.errorStackTrace is not null";
```

Answer (score 1):

You are escaping the table name incorrectly.  Use this raw query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(t1.testName),
       t2.comments AS C1
FROM `sample` AS t1
LEFT JOIN `sample` AS t2
    ON t1.testName = t2.testName
WHERE t1.buildNumber = 181 AND
      t2.buildNumber = 180 AND
      t1.errorStackTrace IS NOT NULL
```

I don't think you really need backticks anywhere.  But in any case, only column *names* need to be backticked, never aliases, e.g.

```
t1.`testName` but NOT `t1.testName`
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrong back quote, try this:

```
$sql3 = "SELECT distinct(t1.`testName`), t2.`comments` AS C1 from `sample` AS t1 left join `sample` AS t2 ON t1.`testName`= t2.`testName` where t1.`buildNumber`= 181 and t2.`buildNumber`= 180 and t1.`errorStackTrace` is not null";
```